# How to Use HTTPS with Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener

Tags: asp.net-core

At the end of this article http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6 it describes how to host a MVC6 app in a Console app using Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.

How can I use https with the weblistener?  I tried changing the url in project.json `"commands": {"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"}` from http and https and that didn't work (although I figured it probably wouldn't be that easy)

What is the format for the `--server.urls` parameter to allow for multiple endpoints (i.e. http and https)?

Comment: Could you modify the question if you're going to accept an answer to a different one?

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have asked two related questions in the same post.  Instead of modifying the question, I revoked the answer (sorry Dusten).  My comment to Dusten's answer renders both questions moot anyway (at least for my purpose).  I find it more convenient to not use https on localhost and by writing an attribute that requires https except when using localhost, I don't have to worry about commenting out requirehttps when testing and then accidentally checking that in.  There are other approaches, but this way works well for me.

Answer (score 4):

Semicolon is the delimiter.

Example:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=http://localhost:12345;http://mydomain.stackoverflow.com:12345"
```

Comment: Thanks, the ; works for multiple URLs.  I'm still not sure how to use SSL when hosting in a console app, but I suspect the process is similar (if not equivalent) to SSL when self hosting an OWIN app.  It's a pain to configure with netsh and new developers have a lot of machine configuration to do.  I settled on overriding the RequireHttpsAttribute so that it doesn't require https when running on localhost.  A crude example can be found at: https://github.com/npnelson/RequireHttpsExceptForLocalHostAttribute.git

Answer (score 0):

For https, the only way I got it to work is adding the following entry into your project.json:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=https://+:12345;
```

Make sure to install the self signed or a commercially purchased public SSL certificate using:

```
netsh http add sslcert
```

command line tool or using a very nice GUI tool by Steve at http://www.stevestechspot.com/HttpConfigUpdate.aspx. Also, remember to give permissions using:

```
netsh add urlacl url=http://+:12345 /yoururl user=Everyone
```

Comment: Hmmm... Your answer looks like it should work (although I think you want to edit your `netsh add...` command to `netsh **http** add...`).  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get your answer to work, but the machine I tried it on isn't very clean.  I will try it again on a cleaner machine when I get a chance and report back.