# Install SSL Certificate for ASP.Net Core Weblistener

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Now that ASP.Net Core has been released I feel it's time to ask this question.

For my web application, I need to use a WebListener server due a business requirement for self-hosting and NTLM authentication for Windows IDs. The Weblistener server needs an SSL Certificate.

I have generated a SSL certificate and know that for Kestrel it is pulled up in the code of the web server (in Program.cs or Startup.cs). But what is the equivalent way to do that for Weblistener?

I found this post: [How to Use HTTPS with Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527331/how-to-use-https-with-microsoft-aspnet-server-weblistener) but it was never truly answered. A couple hours of Googling didn't turn up anything either for me.

From what I can tell it is some kind of command like:

```
netsh http add sslcert
```

But I am in over my head in terms of what I need to do for Weblistener specifically. If possible, I'd love to pull in the certificate using code similar to Kestrel in the startup sequence (it's so convenient!), but I am pretty sure I need to install it with the command line.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/sep/23/hosting-signalr-under-sslhttps, it says SignalR but it's really about http.sys (which is what WebListener is based on)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I'll give that a try this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As davidfowl said, the article https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/sep/23/hosting-signalr-under-sslhttps does outline the process needed and explains it well. It mentions SignalR instead of WebListener but the procedure is the same.

Upon further research if you need to go without IIS (as you might if you are using WebListener because of a business requirement to not be allowed to install IIS) [Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633.aspx) is a good way to generate self-signed certificates or you can use [MMC](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62554187) to obtain a certificate as well.