# Use https with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I need to configure a Asp.net core web application with WebListener as server and https procotols. I wasn't able to find any documentation or faqs about that.

My Progam.cs is:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseWebListener(options => {

             })                
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())               
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:5002")                
            .UseStartup<Startup>()                
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

What can I do for configure WebListener in https?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to bind your SSL certificate to the specific port that your WebListener is listening on, using the `netsh` command.  See [How to: Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx) for more information on how to do this.  After the certificate is bound to the port, you can specify an https url for your WebListener.  You can write code to do the `netsh` part for you (before you start your WebListener), but that probably falls outside the scope of this question.

Enabling https is a lot simpler in Kestrel - any specific reason why you want to use a WebListener?  When using Kestrel, you can do the following (there are also several other overrides that you can use, e.g. use cert from store):

```
new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(options => options.UseHttps(@"C:\MyCert.pfx"));
```

Remember to include the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https` package in your project.json file.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527331/how-to-use-https-with-microsoft-aspnet-server-weblistener) question on StackOverflow that may help to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, I can't use Krestel because my client requests to user WebListener. I aldready made a test with Krestel and it runs fine.

Comment: Understood.  We use the method outlined above (the `netsh` part is done in C# code), so if you can't get it working, please let me know.